# How reliable would it be to use PHP to return a XML file & header

Tags: php, xml, header

I was simply wondering, how reliable would it be to return a XML file through a PHP file, since XML is cached, and I am trying to find a way to easily update the XML file without having to actually clear the cache, and I've came up with a little PHP file that will load the XML file.

What my question is, if you echo a XML file, it comes out as plain text, but if I send the header along with the echo/print_r is it as reliable as if I was to just load the plain .XML file? Or will this cause problems in some browsers?

```
header("Content-type: text/xml");
print_r(file_get_contents("http://xxxx.com/myfile.xml"));
```

Answer (score 0):

that's ok, a lot people render xml using php

load data from net should be cached

json format would be nicer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that it is XML or you use PHP, but the external resource. The main problem is the external URL. You have no control about the external resource and requests to it (from your server) can be limited. If the external service breaks down, so does your proxy.

To make it reliable you should cache the result, so that you have a fallback and do not need to fetch the external URL any time it is requested:

```
$url = 'http://xxxx.com/myfile.xml';
$file = '/local/cache/path/myfile.xml';
$expires = 1800;

header("Content-type: text/xml");

$data = false;
if (
  !file_exists($file) ||
  filemtime($file) + $expires < time()
) {
  $data = file_get_contents($url);
}
if ($data) {
  echo $data;
  file_put_contents($file, $data);
} elseif (($cachedData = file_get_contents($file))) {
  echo $cachedData;
} else {
  // error: can not fetch external url and have no cached data
}
```

This is for a small resource, large resources like data dumps need some more logic (like a separate sync process).